# Graphing O(n^2) Function Using Quadratic Algorithm Returns Linear Graph instead of Standard O(n^2) Graph

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I'm trying to generate a simple graph to show O(n^2) over a thousand items. The code seems to work just fine, however when I plot it using matplotlib, the graph comes out in a linear fashion, meaning the graph of y seems to equal x. I would expect a nice O(n^2) graph like this:

[O(n^2) graph](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/big-o-notation/n-square.png)

I am running my base over 10000 items, still it's linear?

Here is what I'm running:

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

counter = 0
start_time = time.perf_counter()
N = 10000
timings = []
x = []
y = []


for i in range(0, N):
    for j in range(0, N):
        # do something
        pass

    step_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
    timings.append([counter, round(step_time, 2)])

    counter += 1

# NOT efficient code!
for t in timings:
    x.append(t[0])
    y.append(t[1])


plt.xlabel('number of points')
plt.ylabel('time')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title('Quadratic Graph!')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your inner loop does exactly the same amount of work on each iteration of the outer loop - why are you expecting n^2 behavior here?  Making the inner loop `for j in range(i):` might be closer to what you were hoping for - but rounding the times off to two significant digits would likely drown out the actual differences between iterations.

Comment: Did you confuse `continue` and `break`?

Comment: @jasonharper I mean to say "quadratic" I apologize for this!

Comment: How would your edit make it quadratic? Just replace `continue` with `break` in your original code (or use `for j in range(i)` as suggested by @jasonharper) and you'll see a quadratic behaviour.

Comment: I understand that you intend for the code to count cumulative time. However, the inner loop is taking a *constant* amount of time - because it counts up to *the same* `N` value *on each* iteration. The *time taken by your program* is quadratic in the value chosen ahead of time for `N`, however.

Comment: YES!!!!! Thank you ALL, I figured out what I was doing wrong!! @jasonharper, julien and you all pointed me in the right direction. I cannot thank you all enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`O(n²)` means the runtime grows quadratically with the problem size. Your problem size is `n` and you want to print a `n x n` matrix.
`O(n²)` just tells you that you should expect a function with double the input problem size, let's say `n = 5` becomes `n = 10`, will take 4 times as much computing time as `2² = 4`. Obviously all of those are asymptotic measures.
You would see this behavior if you were measuring correctly, but as you only measure how long it takes to print a row (which takes linear time) you only get a linear plot.

To get a correct measurement you will want to run your whole printing the matrix function once with 5, 10, 15, 20, ..., 1000 as an value for `n` and then measure the execution time of the whole function. Then you will get something similar to the expected output.

Consider the following program:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


def measure_runtime(problem_size):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    print_matrix(problem_size)
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    return end_time - start_time


def print_matrix(dim):
    for i in range(0, dim):
        for j in range(0, dim):
            # print(n)
            pass


plt.xlabel('n')
plt.ylabel('Time')
n = 1000
sample_values = range(1, n, 5)
plt.plot(list(sample_values), [measure_runtime(i) for i in sample_values])
plt.title('Quadratic runtime')
plt.show()
```

By the way: If you just wanted to plot a quadratic function you could just plot something like this:

```py
x = list(range(0, 1000))
y = [i ** 2 for i in range(0, 1000)]

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title('Quadratic function')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ok, so I guess I REALLY screwed up when discussing my problem. So the part I eliminated from the code is I'm doing the classic "find a set of points with least distance between them." A classic issue in computer science. I was thinking this is O(n^2) since it involved a double loop. Now you are saying it is not that (fair enough) What is it then?

Comment: No, that's not what I am saying at all. An algorithm which is using a double for loop over `n` is `O(n^2)`. The problem is you're only measuring the runtime of one for loop, not both of them, so what you measure is obviously a linear algorithm `O(n)`, which you measure `n` times. As it always does exactly the same work (= iterate over n values) it will obviously always take the same (or similar) time to execute, therefore your plot will be a line instead of a quadratic function.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, you make a lot of sense. No matter if I run the outer loop thousands of times, the inner loop will still be running independently. I think that is the key there (please correct me if I'm wrong.) I adjusted my code to follow your guidelines and it now works correctly.